# Solving simultaneous recurrences

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations

I've been reading about characteristic equations for recurrence relations and I was wondering how one would solve a simultaneous recurrence, such as

$$f(n) =c_1g(n-1) +c_2f(n-1)+ c_3$$
$$g(n) = d_1f(n-2)+d_2g(n-2)+d_3$$

where $c_i,d_i\in\mathbb{R}$ for $i=1,2,3$

Comment: You can write it in matrix form: $x(n) = \begin{pmatrix} f(n)\\g(n)\\\dots\end{pmatrix}$; and express the recurrence relation as $x(n) = Ax(n-1)+b$ for some matrix $A$ and some constant vector $b$. In your case, the vector may need to be of dimension $>2$ to include $f(n), g(n), f(n-1), g(n-1)$ (i.e., your specific problem can be written as a recurrence relation including vectors of size $4$ and a $4\times 4$ matrix).

Comment: @ClementC. What about the "$(n-2)$" terms though?

Comment: If you have $x(n) = \begin{pmatrix} f(n)\\g(n)\\f(n-1)\\g(n-1)\end{pmatrix}$, then the $n-2$ terms will appear in $x(n-1)$. (But the matrix will be $4\times 4$).

Comment: @ClementC. sorry I didn't see the edit you made

Comment: @ClementC.so the solutions correspond to the eigenvalues of the matrix?